# Match iOS in-app purchase receipt with user's purchase history

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

We're using in-app purchases in our app and validating receipts on server side.

As a result of validation we get `Receipt` object described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html). We store the `transaction_id` in our records as a unique identifier of the purchase.

Then, some time after the purchase a user who made a purchase in our app looks at **Purchase History** in the iTunes app and see this identifiers:

[image: iTunes purchase identifiers]

**Question:**
How can we match this identifiers with the validated receipt?

For example, it's useful in the case when users contact us via support channels and want to restore their accounts.